# libtcl8.4.so is needed by python-2.7.10-1.ppc AIX 7.1

Tags: tcl, rpm, tk-toolkit, aix, yum

I'm trying to install apache on aix 7.1. I'm following : https://developer.ibm.com/articles/au-aix-install-config-apache-subversions/
but i'm stuck at rpm `-ivh *.rpm` because of dependencies.
Getting an error:

> libtcl8.4.so is needed by python-2.7.10-1.ppc
>
> libtk8.4.so is needed by python-2.7.10-1.ppc

I've tried installing tcl and tk packages and installed.

> tcl-8.6.7-1.aix5.1.ppc.rp
>
> tk-8.6.7-1.aix5.1.ppc.rpm

but i'm still getting the same error. How do i resolve this issue.

Comment: I want to install httpd.

Comment: Then install `apr`, `apr-util` and `httpd`, you don't need Subversion, Python, Tcl and Tk.

Comment: Python 2.7.10 is quite out of date… and so is Tcl 8.4 and Tk 8.4 (those are both outright unsupported now).

Comment: I've installed apr apr-util, still not succesful, can you please share ful procedure so that i'm not missing anything.

Comment: _What_ is not successfull? You were told you don't need subversion, python, tcl or tk. Please edit your original post and describe what did you do and what is the problem. Possible download location: http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Apache64

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur in other contexts, as well. I ran into it when trying to install yum on an AIX 7.1 system. It uses the same ancient versions of python and tk/tcl.

I found the answer here: https://www.djouxtech.net/posts/aix-yum-installation/

The libtcl and libtk libraries must be version 8.4.x, 8.6.x will not work.

They come not from another RPM, but are native to AIX. You have to install the packages tk.base and tcl.base from your AIX install media.

The command you need will be similar to this:

```
installp -a -d <location of your media> tk.base
installp -a -d <location of your media> tcl.base
```

Disclaimer: I have not yet tested this.